# syntax of ffmpeg vignette backward command

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg

I have searched but not found an answer for this particular question.  I am trying to use the reverse the vignetting effect so the corners are made brighter.
From the docs:
‘backward’The larger the distance from the central point, the brighter the image becomes. This can be used to reverse a vignette effect, though there is no automatic detection to extract the lens angle and other settings (yet). It can also be used to create a burning effect. 
Default value is ‘forward’.
I cannot find a correct way to include the 'backward' command.   I also cannot find a sample command that uses it.   Could someone provide me with a sample vignette command that includes 'backward'

This is working for me
 ffmpeg -i video -vf vignette=angle=PI/4 output, but I cannot find a correct way to add 'backward'   I keep getting syntax errors....
Thanks for any help,
John

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is `-vf vignette=angle=PI/4:mode=backward`. See https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtergraph-syntax-1 for an exact but technical description of syntax rules. See examples attached to many filters for illustration e.g. https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtergraph-syntax-1